# GC clean up String object in a List in java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In java, a huge amount of String object is stored in the java ArrayList object, after processing, GC should clean up those String object as soon as possible so that heap will not overflow.

I am using GC CMS as follows. I check GC log, old generation space is full.

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:SurvivorRatio=4
```

Do you have any ideas to fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to see the code behind this.  For instance, if your code is unnecessarily creating many large temporary strings, then this would be a place for improvement rather than blaming the garbage collector.

Comment: GS will *always* try to free some space before you run out of memory.

Comment: Strings are different because of interning and perm space (at least prior to JDK 8).  You have other issues.

Comment: Are you _actually_ getting a memory overflow? The GC can choose to defer the clean up of unused objects, till it's actually running out of memory.